# How to process a Table.column which contains a SQL logic in Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Eg :

Table - MappingTable

| Col1 | Col2 | MappingLogic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | SELECT * FROM TableX |
| One | Two | SELECT * FROM TableX X Left Outer Join TableY Y on X.id=Y.ID |

Other Tables - TableX and TableY

How Can I use this mapping table in Pyspark dataframe and build my logic using MappingLogic column ??

Comment: How do you want to use the queries in your application logic?

Comment: Hi, Can you please confirm if the Mapping Table is a spark/delta (any others within Databricks) table or a table in any of the RDBMS systems like SQL Server or PostgreSQL ? If it is a table inside databricks, you could extract the column to a variable `qry = spark.sql("SELECT MappingLogic from MappingTable where <WHERE_CLAUSE>").collect()[0][0]` and pass that to a `spark.sql(qry)` to execute...If it is a SQL DB like SQL Server, answer provided below should work perfectly....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of answer are you expecting, but in general you can use sql expressions in your `pyspark` code. You just have to create views on your tables first:

```py
spark.read \
    .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "tableX",
          properties={"user": "username", "password": "password"}).createOrReplaceTempView("tableX")

# Later you get sql-expression from your mapping logic table and execute it:
s = "SELECT * FROM TableX"
df = spark.sql(s)
```